# DataTable to csv file

Tags: javascript, java, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have created a web page using bootstrap/thymeleaf where I show some data tables using Ajax. And I have the buttons to export to CSV, but what I need is to generate a temporary file from this datatable and get the path to my controller when the datatable is already loaded with the data using a button.

So I need a way to do that creating a new function, but I don't really know how to do it. May be without call again my sql repository because tables are very large.

JavaScript Code

```
function mostrarMaticulaEstudiant(data) {

    var url = "/9avaldoval/administracio/cercarMaticulaEstudiant?idEdicio=" + data;
    dataTableMatriculaEstudiant(url);
}

function dataTableMatriculaEstudiant(url) {

    var columns;
    var columnsConfig;
    var columnsFiltres;

    columns = crearColumnesTaulaMatriculaEstudiant();
    //columnsConfig = configurarColumnaBotonsEstudis(columns.length);
    var sorting = [[0, "asc"]];

    var htmlTable = crearTaulaHtmlMatriculaEstudiant(14);

    $('#divTaula').html(htmlTable);


    var table = $('#taulaMatriculaEstudiant').DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        processing: false,
        ajaxSource: url,
        fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData = $("#formAdmBlue").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            });
        },

        columns: columns,
        columnDefs: columnsConfig,
        sorting: sorting,
        language: {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostra _MENU_ files per pàgina",
            "search": "Filtre: ",
            "zeroRecords": "Sense resultats",
            "info": "Pàgina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "Files no trobades a la cerca",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrat de _MAX_ files totals)",
            "sProcessing": "<img src='/9avaldoval/img/loading_gear.gif' width='48px' height='48px'>",
            "paginate": {
                "next": "<span class='oi oi-chevron-right'></span>",
                "previous": "<span class='oi oi-chevron-left'></span>"
            }
        },
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        error: function() {
            alert("No s'ha pogut obtenir la informació");
        }
    });


}


function crearTaulaHtmlMatriculaEstudiant(numColumnes) {

    var htmlTableOpen = '<table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover" id="taulaMatriculaEstudiant"><thead>';

    var htmlTableHeaderRow = '<tr>';
    var htmlTh = '<th></th>';
    for (var i = 0; i < numColumnes; i++) {
        htmlTableHeaderRow = htmlTableHeaderRow + htmlTh;
    }
    htmlTableHeaderRow = htmlTableHeaderRow + '</tr>';
    var htmlTableClose = '</thead></table>';
    var htmlTable = htmlTableOpen + htmlTableHeaderRow + htmlTableClose;
    return htmlTable;

}


function crearColumnesTaulaMatriculaEstudiant() {


    var columns = [];
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdAssigEdicio", "mData": "IdAssigEdicio", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdEdicio", "mData": "IdEdicio", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdCodiassigPare", "mData": "IdCodiassigPare", "sWidth": "10%", "className": "text-center", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdUsuariUPF", "mData": "IdUsuariUPF", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdCodiAssigFill", "mData": "IdCodiAssigFill", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "IdAssigFill", "mData": "IdAssigFill", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "EsRepetidor", "mData": "EsRepetidor", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "CodiCentreEstudiant", "mData": "CodiCentreEstudiant", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "CentreEstudiant", "mData": "CentreEstudiant", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "EstudiEstudiant", "mData": "EstudiEstudiant", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "CodiEstudiEstudiantL", "mData": "CodiEstudiEstudiantL", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "DescEstudi_es", "mData": "DescEstudi_es", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "DescEstudi_en", "mData": "DescEstudi_en", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });
    columns.push({ "sTitle": "DescEstudi_ca", "mData": "DescEstudi_ca", "sWidth": "10%", "defaultContent": "" });

    return columns;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cercarMaticulaEstudiant", params = "idEdicio")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] cercarMaticulaEstudiant(@RequestParam("idEdicio") String idEdicio, Model model)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ParseException {

        log.debug("***** cercarEdicions AJAX ****");

        byte[] dataTableSource = null;
        List<BlueMatriculaEstudiant> llistaMatriculaEstudiants;

        llistaMatriculaEstudiants = blueMatriculaEstudiantService
                .cercarBlueMatriculaEstudiant(Integer.parseInt(idEdicio));

        dataTableSource = operacionsService.blueMatriculaEstudiantsToJson(llistaMatriculaEstudiants);

        return dataTableSource;
    }
```

HTML/Bootstrap

```
<div class="col-lg-12" 
                        style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        <br>
                        <div class="card">
                            <h5 class="card-header" th:id="llistat"
                                data-th-text="#{administracio.blue.llistat}"></h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row"
                                    style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div id="divTaula"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create the `csv` files using JS on the client-side.

First of all, you will need to get the data from your `DataTable`, [their documentation shows it could be done like this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()):

```
let table = $('#taulaMatriculaEstudiant').DataTable()
 
let data = table
    .rows()
    .data()
```

Now, `csv` format is basically a text format with separators. So you need to iterate over the rows in `data` and merge cells to separate text rows, something like this:

```
let text = '';
data.map( row => text += row.join( ';' ) + '\n' ) // replace ';' with your preferred CSV separator
```

Then you only need to create a document and download it. To do that I would suggest the usage of [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/):

```
let blob = new Blob( [text], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"} )
saveAs( blob, 'taulaMatriculaEstudiant.csv' ) // any name with CSV extension
```

**Please note** that I have never worked with `DataTables`, so I might be mistaken about the data structure in which it returns the data from table after `.rows().data()` (I assumed it returns an array of arrays that represent the cells in the rows). The general approach should be correct.

**Edit**

However I would not recommend sending data from the browser to the server - just create the correct file on the server side insted. E.g. like this:

```
@Controller // note it's not @RestController
public class CsvController {
    private CommonDataService dataService; // service with your table data logic. Don't forget to add @Service to it

    @GetMapping( "/csv/example" )
    public void exampleCsv( HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
        byte[] processedFile = dataService.getTaulaMatriculaEstudiant(); // prepare your data the same way as your main data controller and create the csv table the way you like it

        ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition.builder( "attachment" )
            .filename( "taulaMatriculaEstudiant.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )
            .build();
        response.setContentType( "text/csv" );
        response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
        response.setHeader( "Expires", "0" );
        response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );

        IOUtils.copy( new ByteArrayInputStream( processedFile ), response.getOutputStream() ); // IOUtils from Apache Commons-IO
    } 

    @Autowired
    public void setDataService( CommonDataService dataService ) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understantd it and I make it work, but there is any way to make and invisible download to the user or make this file temporal? Because I would like to erase the file after do another thing with it, but without being seen by the user

Comment: I think the best way would be to prepare the data server-side without scraping the client-side tables. E.g. you could create a new `@Controller` (better not REST) GET-request method which would use the same logic as `cercarMaticulaEstudiant()` to prepare the information. Then simply process it and create a file that you need and then return it to user. No need to send data back and forth. I will expand my answer with instructions on how to download a file. However, you could transform your `blob` to Base64 string using JS's `FileReader` and send it via AJAX if you absolutely have to.

Comment: Okey I will look into it, but there is no need to create a new service right? I can still using blueMatriculaEstudiantService as my data service or would be some problem?

Comment: Yes of course, I just used that as an example for code abstraction (that you can use same logic to obtain data in both cases)

Comment: This is pretty new to me and there are some things that I don't get it, so this file where will be saved? Or how can  I get the path. Another thing is how can I delete after use it or will be deleted automatically

Comment: So the way I suggested - it will be added as an Attachment to the response. Which means it will be automatically downloaded to client’s PC the way it is configured (e.g. Downloads folder). You don’t have to delete it or anything.